# User access on SharePoint

Tags: user, site-usage, analytics, usage-counters

I know that Popularity Trends or Most Popular Items (For Document Libraries) can provide how many Unique users or hits are accessing pages, sites, documents, etc. and what day/ month this took place on.
Is there a way to find the exact user name of each person that has accessed a page/ file and the date/ time?

If this is not possible is it possible to have a popup list form which stays in front of the page until the user has submitted his name, after which the page becomes visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through Site Collection Audit Logs:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131

Excerpt:

> Events available for audit log reports The following events are
>   available for audit log reports to help you determine who is taking
>   what actions with the content of a site collection:
>
> Opened and downloaded documents, viewed items in lists, or viewed item
>   properties (This event is not available for SharePoint Online sites)
>
> Edited items
>
> Checked out and checked in items
>
> Items that have been moved and copied to other location in the site
>   collection
>
> Deleted and restored items
>
> Changes to content types and columns
>
> Search queries
>
> Changes to user accounts and permissions
>
> Changed audit settings and deleted audit log events
>
> Workflow events
>
> Custom events

If you are using SharePoint Online, it also is in the Unified Audit Logs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance